# How to sort DataProvider after updating its models in yii2?

Tags: sorting, yii2, dataprovider

I got some data from database.

```
$searchModel = new InventorySearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

The revenue and the cost of each product are calulated using a complex algorithm. After that the $dataProvider is updated with the new costs and revenues as below:

[image: Gridview]

```
foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {

        $model->cost = 0;
        $model->revenue = 0;
        $model->profit = 0;
        $model->profit_margin = 0;

        foreach($calculated_costs as $item)
        {
            if($model->id == $item['product_id'])
            {
                $model->cost  = $item['total_cost'];
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach($calculated_revenue as $rev_item)
        {
            if($model->id == $rev_item['product_id'])
            {
                $model->revenue  = $rev_item['total_sales'];
                break;
            }
        }

        $model->profit = floatval($model->revenue)  - floatval($model->cost) ;
        if($model->revenue != 0)
        {
            $model->profit_margin = ( floatval($model->profit) ) /  floatval($model->revenue) ;
        }

    }
```

I need to sort the dataprovider by profit after updating the dataprovider. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hi Aldfonso, do please, describe more about calculating. What, where and how exactly do you calculate? Better add some code samples ;)

Comment: Hello soovorow, I have updated the question

Comment: where are you get `$calculated_costs` and `$calculated_revenue`? That seems like you trying to get value from relation models, that is right?

Comment: $calculated_costs and $calculated_revenue are calculated by the algorithm.